# Sync with iCal through Sync Services

Tags: cocoa, core-data, service, synchronization, icalendar

I'm looking for sample code on how to sync with ical through sync services. Or anything that can point me to the right direction on how to do it. I've already gotten sync services up and running for my own core data schema, but I am not sure on how to do it with iCal.

I found the calendar schema on apple docs on the link below, but have no idea on how to start implementing it with sync services.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SyncServicesSchemaRef/Articles/Calendars.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001540-CJBEHAAG

Thank you,
Jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're syncing with iCal, why not sync with the [CalCalendarStore](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/CalendarStoreFramework/Classes/CalCalendarStore_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and let SyncServices sync iCal as it's likely already doing?

Comment: Ok, will look into it.. I may inferred wrong that Apple pushes us to do it through Sync services, since at top of the documentation states that if you "already syncing through sync services you don't need to sync through the calendar framework",,, thanks.